# ORA-01861: literal does not match format string in jsp

Tags: jsp

I am trying to insert few values into oracle table (oracle 10g) using JSP. I have been encountering ORA-01861 error... Can some one please help me out.

```
int eid = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("srno"));
String enm = "";
int exit_tp = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("applntype"));
int ecadre = 0;
String ecdr = "";
String epost = "";
String edob = "";
String eappt_da = "";
String ecadre_date = "";
String edor = "";
String esubmitted_by = "";
String esubmitted_ip = "";
String ezn = "";
String ezone = "";
String edivision = "";
String ebranch = "";

String tmp = "select ep.name,ep.cadre,cd.descpn,epv.post,ep.dob,ef.appt_da,ep.cadre_date,add_months(ep.dob-1,720),z.short,ep.zone,ep.division,ep.branch " +
        "from empfile ef,emp_prov ep,v$emp_prov epv,cadre cd,zone z " +
        "where ep.srno=epv.srno(+) " +
        "and ef.srno=ep.srno(+) " +
        "and ep.cadre=cd.code(+) " +
        "and ep.zone=z.zn(+) " +
        "and ep.srno=" + eid;

PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(tmp);

ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery();

if (rset.next()) {
    enm = rset.getString(1);
    ecadre = rset.getInt(2);
    ecdr = rset.getString(3);
    epost = rset.getString(4);
    edob = rset.getString(5);
    eappt_da = rset.getString(6);
    ecadre_date = rset.getString(7);
    edor = rset.getString(8);
    ezn = rset.getString(9);
    ezone = rset.getString(10);
    edivision = rset.getString(11);
    ebranch = rset.getString(12);
}
rset.close();
stmt.close();

String tmp1 = "insert into online_exit(srno,name,exitcode,cadre,post,dob,appt_da,cadre_date,dor,submit_date,submit_stt,zone,division,branch) " +
        "values (?,?,?,?,?,to_date(?,'DD/MM/YYYY'),to_date(?,'DD/MM/YYYY'),to_date(?,'DD/MM/YYYY'),to_date(?,'DD/MM/YYYY'),SYSDATE,2,?,?,?)";

PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(tmp1);

pstmt.setInt(1, eid);
pstmt.setString(2, enm);
pstmt.setInt(3, exit_tp);
pstmt.setInt(4, ecadre);
pstmt.setString(5, epost);
pstmt.setString(6, edob);
pstmt.setString(7, eappt_da);
pstmt.setString(8, ecadre_date);
pstmt.setString(9, edor);
pstmt.setString(10, ezone);
pstmt.setString(11, edivision);
pstmt.setString(12, ebranch);

pstmt.executeUpdate();

pstmt.close();
conn.close();
```

The description of the table is as follows

```
Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ------------
 SRNO                                      NOT NULL NUMBER(6)
 NAME                                               VARCHAR2(50)
 EXITCODE                                           NUMBER(2)
 CADRE                                              NUMBER(2)
 POST                                               VARCHAR2(30)
 DOB                                                DATE
 APPT_DA                                         DATE
 CADRE_DATE                                         DATE
 CONF_STT                                           VARCHAR2(3)
 DOR                                                DATE
 VIG_DIS_STT                                        VARCHAR2(50)
 APPLN_DA                                           DATE
 APPLN_ACK_DA                                       DATE
 REC_CO_DA                                          DATE
 PREF_EXIT_DA                                       DATE
 NOTICE_PER_EXP_DA                                  DATE
 REASON                                             VARCHAR2(50)
 PENSION_OPT                                        VARCHAR2(2)
 REVERSN                                            VARCHAR2(2)
 COMP_AUTH                                          NUMBER
 EXIT_DATE                                          DATE
 SUBITTED_BY                                        NUMBER(6)
 SUBMIT_DATE                                        DATE
 SUBMITTED_IP                                       VARCHAR2(15)
 VALIDATED_BY                                       NUMBER(6)
 VALIDATED_ON                                       DATE
 VALIDATE_IP                                        VARCHAR2(15)
 SUBMIT_STT                                         NUMBER(2)
 ZONE                                               VARCHAR2(2)
 DIVISION                                           VARCHAR2(3)
 BRANCH                                             VARCHAR2(4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ResultSet#getDate()` method to return `java.sql.Date` and call the `PreparedStatement#setDate()` method to assign `java.sql.Date` to the parameter.

```
java.sql.Date edob;
...
if (rset.next()) {
  ..... 
  edob = rset.getDate(5);
  ....
}
....
String tmp1 = "insert into online_exit(srno,name,exitcode,cadre,post,dob,appt_da,cadre_date,dor,"
             +"submit_date,submit_stt,zone,division,branch) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(tmp1);

.....
pstmt.setDate(6, edob);
.....
```

NOTE: If you have string date then use `SimpleDateFormat` methods to parse the string date.

EDIT:

> when i tried to initialize java.sql.Date edob = new java.sql.Date(), I am getting "The constructor Date() is undefined" error

You've to instantiate the `java.sql.Date` by passing millis to its constructor:

```
java.sql.Date edob=new java.sql.Date(new java.util.Date().getTime());
//Or use java.sql.Date.valueOf() method
java.sql.Date date=java.sql.Date.valueOf("2012-12-31");
```

Comment: thanks for replying.....i have tried the above shown method... when i tried to initialize java.sql.Date edob = new java.sql.Date(), I am getting "The constructor Date() is undefined" error...